# Angular service destroy on page leave

Tags: angular

I have a service, `TransactionsProvider` that is included in a page module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    SharedModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    ClientDetailPage,
  ],
  providers: [
    TransactionsProvider,
  ],
  exports: [
  ]
})
export class ClientDetailPageModule {}
```

My `TransactionsProvider` implements `OnDestroy` however it does not seem to be destryoed when `ClientDetailPage` is destroyed.

```
@Injectable()
export class TransactionsProvider implements OnDestroy {

  base_url: string;
  auth_token: string;

  purchased_weeks = new BehaviorSubject(<number>0);
  purchased_weeks$ = this.purchased_weeks.asObservable()

  purchases$: Observable<ITransaction[]>;
  payments$: Observable<ITransaction[]>;

  constructor(private globalVarService: GlobalsService,
              private commentsService: CommentsProvider,
              private http: HttpClient ) {
    this.base_url = this.globalVarService.base_url;
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    console.log("destroy txn service")
  }

  ...

}
```

I never see `destroy txn service` in the console so I assume the service is not being destroyed.  What do I need to do so my service get's destroyed when the page is destroyed?

Answer (score 0):

It depends from the dependency injection. For the services, you use the same instance in all module o in all app (if you use provided in root). To use an instance of the service only for you component, you have to declare it as provider for the component. You can do that in this way:

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'app-selector',
  templateUrl: './my-app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-app.component.css'],
  providers: [TransactionsProvider]
})
```

Comment: I need it throughout the entire module, not in the individual component.  It is NOT provicded in root.  Is there a way to destroy the service when the module is destroyed?  Do modules get destroyed?